# How to find all duplicate assets in AEM dam?

Tags: aem, assets, dam

I need to find all the duplicated assets in DAM.

I followed https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/author/assets/managing-assets-touch-ui/duplicate-detection.html

This document is not helping me in searching for all duplicate values. Also, it doesn't tell that i am uploading a duplicate asset. It just pops-up a window asking for replacing or create new version for that asset.

My priority is to get list of all duplicated DAM assets. Please advise

Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wqYE.png)

Comment: Hi,

I tried uploading an image asset in Touch UI and it seems Duplicate-Detection working there. I got a pop-up window telling me that duplicates values are present.

Could you please tell me how can i generate a report (or a list ) to get all duplicate assets in one go?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK when you enable the **detect duplicate**, The behavior will be in the following way.

**Touch UI :**  when you try to upload and then try to Create Version/Replace the asset  which is already present. It will populate a popup notating same.
[image: Touci UI Duplicate Image]
 **Classic UI :** It will end up throwing an error with out asking such as Touch UI popup as shown below.
 *I guess Adobe has concentrated only on the Touch UI implementation*.
[image: Classic UI]

When you upload the asset to aem it will create a lot properties for the DAM Assets, one of the property is `dam:sha1`, The **detect duplicate** logic will work based on this property value data.

And to get the list of duplicate assets paths you can use a **XPATH** query

> //element(*, dam:Asset)[(jcr:content/metadata/@dam:sha1 =
>   'ff546dd8055fcfca53471dfa6fe0494c4198e965')]

Where in the "**ff546dd8055fcfca53471dfa6fe0494c4198e965**" value is of my image `dam:sha1` property value. find the below screenshot for reference.[image]

Comment: Not sure if this helps. sha1 value will change if XMP writebacks are enabled so detecting duplicates may not work using dam:sha1 query after that. Just an edge case you should be aware of when implementing above approach.

Comment: I think the issue was with AEM 6.0 and 6.1. But when I tested with 6.2, this  detect duplicate  is working fine. In this way I can detect if the Asset is already present in the DAM or not. But the main query is if I can just detect all DAM duplicate assets which are already there, using SHA values.